# How to write a list to Excel column?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have a list of some values in Python and want to write them into an Excel-Spreadsheet column using openpyxl.

So far I tried, where `lstStat` is a list of integers that needs to be written to the Excel column:

```
for statN in lstStat:
    for line in ws.range('A3:A14'):
        for cell in line:
            cell.value(statN)
```

I'm getting a `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable` for the last line in the code snippet.

Can you help me out how to write my data to the Excel column?

Comment: `cell.value` is not a function, hence is not callable

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To assign a value to a cell, use `=`:

```
cell.value = statN
```

You also need to fix your loops.  Notice that right now, for *each* element in `lstStat`, you are writing the *entire range*.  Besides not being what you intended, it also is less flexible:  What happens if `lstStat` has more or fewer elements?

What you want to do is just loop over `lstStat` and increment the row number as you go.  Something like

```
r = 3
for statN in lstStat:
    ws.cell(row=r, column=1).value = statN
    r += 1
```

You could also use Python's `enumerate` function:

```
for r, statN in enumerate(lstStat, start=3):
    ws.cell(row=r, column=1).value = statN
```

(Note that A1 is referenced as `cell(row=1, column=1)` as of [OpenPyXL version 2.0.0](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/changes.html#id300); in earlier versions, A1 was `cell(row=0, column=0)`.)

Comment: Hmm, that does the trick... :)
Unfortunately, it writes every value of the list to every cell in the range and I end up in having the range filled with only the last value... ;)

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook,Workbook

wb=load_workbook('Book1.xlsx')
ws1=wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

shs=wb.get_sheet_names()
print(type(shs))
# shs is list

for r in range(0,len(shs)):
    ws1.cell(row=r+1,column=1).value=shs[r]

wb.save('Book1.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 1):

Openpyxl does not allow you to write lists in excel cells, however if you convert the list into a string you can paste it into excel.

e.g. This would cause an error

`my_list = ['1','2','3']
 ws.cell(row=r, column=1).value = my_list`

However this would paste the string of the list into excel

`my_list = ['1','2','3']
 new_list = str(my_list)
 ws.cell(row=r, column=1).value = new_list`