# Select specific cells for range function in openpyxl package of Python

Tags: python, excel, append, range, openpyxl

I have this code:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

for i in range(10):
   ws.append([i])
```

This writes `range(10)` (0-9 values) from `A1` to `A10`. How we can change these cell to other cells? for example from `B1` to `B10` or from `A1` to `J10`?

Comment: I believe v similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15004838/42346

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ws.append(seq)` treats the sequence or iterable passed in as a whole row. The first value will be for the first column. If you want the first value to be for another column then you will need to pad the sequence with `None`.

Something like the following will add four rows of ten values starting in the fifth column.

```
seq = [None] * 4  + list(range(10))
for i in range(10):
   ws.append(seq)
```

For more control use `ws.cell()`as covered in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you for answer. How we can use `ws.cell()` in this specific case?

Comment: It's covered in the documentation.