# Using Loop to Add Values of a List to Cells in an Excel Worksheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas, for-loop, while-loop

I would like to find a method for adding the values of a list to specific cells of a excel worksheet that I have created. I want to take the list "col_test" and add the values to the second (2nd) column beginning in the sixth (6th) row and then populate down that column until there are no more values in the list. Thank you for the help.

My code is this so far. My guess is that I need some type of a loop but I am not sure how to go about it. Thank you.

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

for csvfile in glob.glob(os.path.join('.', '*.csv')):
    df = pd.read_csv(csvfile)

col_test = df['Test #'].tolist()
col_retest = df['Retest #'].tolist()

from xlrd import open_workbook
from xlutils.copy import copy

rb = open_workbook("Excel FDT Master_01_update.xlsx")
wb = copy(rb)
s = wb.get_sheet(3)
s.write('B6', col_test)
```

As of now I am getting an error message that tells me the index is out of range for the last line of code - s.write('B6', col_test)

Comment: you probably have to provide a small data set in your question that you use when you get the failure. Have you checked the len/sizes of what you have in your variables. I have not read the docs for xlrd, but the last line looks strange, you attempt to write a list to cell B6?

Comment: I found this and I am wondering if it will do what I need:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004838/how-to-write-a-list-to-xlsx-using-openpyxl

Comment: something along those lines yes, but that question was for openpyxl, you are using xlrd... just try your code putting a single value in the write, if it works your index error comes from that you ask to write a list into a single cell. Have you tried to read the documentation for xlrd? They are normally quite good with useful examples.

Comment: actually, you already have pandas installed, why do you first make a list and then write the excel, why not just use pandas to write the excel, i.e. fix your dataframe so that it looks like you want, and then just do `df.to_excel()`.